# Unable to create the cache directory (/cache/)

Tags: symfony, caching

Trying to continue my development, but since I installed Fedora the error

> RuntimeException in bootstrap.php.cache line 2671: Unable to create the cache directory (/cache/)

does not disappear. Every folder is `777`. And no suggestion has helped me.

I've installed PHP separately, and I am using its build-in server to develop. Only in Fedora using Xfce has shown me this problem.

By the way, the folder is already there too. It doesn't make  any sense. It never happened before.

Comment: What exact directory is "there" already?

Comment: You have to check the presence of the cache directory on `app/cache/` of your Symfony application.

Comment: is it really `/cache`? this looks like it shall be placed under the root directory `/` like in `/tmp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php symfony2 installation cache permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845666/php-symfony2-installation-cache-permissions)